# WCF: Are metadata required to consume WCF service?

Tags: wcf, wcfserviceclient

I created WCF service (last year) that is consumed by Silverlight application and it doesn't have metadata (doesn't have IMetadataExchange endpoint).

Now I need WCF service to be consumed by windows console application and I can't add reference to service. I click 'Add Service' discover solution's services, selected 'required' service and clicked 'Ok' button.

Instead of service reference created I got the following error:

> The HTML document does not contain Web
>   service discovery information.
>   Metadata contains a reference that
>   cannot be resolved:
>   'http://localhost/EnrollmentService.svc'.
>   There was no endpoint listening at
>   http://localhost/EnrollmentService.svc
>   that could accept the message. This is
>   often caused by an incorrect address
>   or SOAP action. See InnerException, if
>   present, for more details. The remote
>   server returned an error: (404) Not
>   Found. If the service is defined in
>   the current solution, try building the
>   solution and adding the service
>   reference again.

Should I work on adding metadata support for WCF service or it should be another solution?

Please advice.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `WCF Service` without exposing metadata.

Metadata is used to generate a proxy by `Visual Studio` or any other tool. So, in case you don't expose metadata, you are going to have to create/write these proxy classes yourself.

As long as you use correct service address and right data contracts, you are good to go.

[Accessing WCF service without creating Proxy](http://debugmode.net/2010/10/31/accessing-wcf-service-without-creating-proxy/)

Comment: So I need to generate those proxy's myself? no, I would better add metadata support... But thank you for your answer

Comment: Take a look at the link added. Its worth knowing how to do it.

Comment: I've token. But thanks, I would better go with metadata. In my case services has a lot of parameters, are subject of change, so need to be easy-to-support. That will be provided by metadata.